# Get value of constant by name

Tags: c#, field, constants

I have a class with constants. I have some string, which can be same as name of one of that constants or not.

So class with constants `ConstClass` has some `public const` like `const1, const2, const3...`

```
public static class ConstClass
{
    public const string Const1 = "Const1";
    public const string Const2 = "Const2";
    public const string Const3 = "Const3";
}
```

To check if class contains `const` by name i have tried next :

```
var field = (typeof (ConstClass)).GetField(customStr);
if (field != null){
    return field.GetValue(obj) // obj doesn't exists for me
}
```

Don't know if it's realy correct way to do that, but now i don't know how to get value, cause `.GetValue` method need obj of type `ConstClass` (ConstClass is static)

Comment: Could you please reorganize your question, and show your code so that it's easier to follow? (instead of *describing* your code, which is *hard* to follow)

Comment: Instead of using some constants and reflection to get them i would strongly recommend to use a `Dictionary<string, string>`. That's more efficient, more maintainable and also more readable.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

To get field values or call members on static types using reflection you pass `null` as the instance reference.

Here is a short [LINQPad](http://linqpad.net) program that demonstrates:

```
void Main()
{
    typeof(Test).GetField("Value").GetValue(null).Dump();
    // Instance reference is null ----->----^^^^
}

public class Test
{
    public const int Value = 42;
}
```

Output:

```
42
```

Please note that the code as shown will not distinguish between normal fields and const fields.

To do that you must check that the field information also contains the flag `Literal`:

Here is a short LINQPad program that only retrieves constants:

```
void Main()
{
    var constants =
        from fieldInfo in typeof(Test).GetFields()
        where (fieldInfo.Attributes & FieldAttributes.Literal) != 0
        select fieldInfo.Name;
    constants.Dump();
}

public class Test
{
    public const int Value = 42;
    public static readonly int Field = 42;
}
```

Output:

```
Value
```

Comment: This was of great help, but I had to tweak it some because my function passes in a `Type` parameter.  My implementation looks something like `(myPassedType as Type).GetField("Value").GetValue(null)`.

Answer (score 7):

```
string customStr = "const1";

if ((typeof (ConstClass)).GetField(customStr) != null)
{
    string value = (string)typeof(ConstClass).GetField(customStr).GetValue(null);
}
```

Comment: Are you going to explain your code and how this fixes the issue?

Comment: No not really it's quite self explanatory. The OP asked how to get the value of the const variable and that is the answer.

Comment: string customStr = "const1"; does not include the 'const' keyword, therefore it is not a constant variable. As such, self-explanatory or not, this is not an answer to the question.

Comment: @vynsane, `customStr` contains name of constant, value of which is needed.